# Get AppointmentItem data when Send is triggered

Tags: vba, outlook

When I send an Outlook 2016 appointment, I use following to trigger a VBA code:

```
Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
```

How to display data specific to the type "AppointmentItem"?

I expect a Message Box "Do you want to talk about Computer at school",
but I get a Run-time error '438'.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim prompt As String
    prompt = "Do you want to talk about " & Item.Subject    'Works
    prompt = prompt & " at " & Item.Location                'Error
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send a meeting request, the sent item itself is an `olMeetingRequest` and not an `olAppoinmentItem`.

You can address the corresponding appointment item by [GetAssociatedAppointment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.getassociatedappointment)

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objAppointment As AppointmentItem
    If Item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
        Set objAppointment = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)
        Debug.Print objAppointment.Subject
        Debug.Print objAppointment.Location
    End If
End Sub
```